# is there a way to change the submodule name dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging

I have a bunch of codegenerated files:

```
parent/
  a.py
  b.py
  <...>
  aa.py
```

They import each other assuming they are at the root of whatever package they are in.

e.g. `a.py`:

```
import b as b__
```

I want to include the entire `parent` subdir into another project, so that the resulting tree looks like

```
project/
  main.py
  parent/
    a.py
    b.py
    <...>
```

However, everything in parent in the above tree then has issues importing each other. Is there a way to fix that other than by going into each of `a.py`, `b.py`, ...., and making all the absolute imports into relative imports? e.g. doing the below 100 times:

```
import .b as b__
```

Comment: if `a.py` is visible as `a` (for your existing .py files) and `parent.a` (for new stuff in your new project), that's two different modules and two different namespaces as far as python is concerned. I see typing in your future....

Comment: yeah, I was hoping that there was a way to trick the loader for everything in `parent/` so that they think that they are in a different namespace. The correct way to do this entire thing is to I guess publish all of `parent` as a proper python module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can manipulate the import mechanism by running `import sys; sys.path.append('path/to/project/parent')` as the very first line of code before anything else happens. Or similarly, [set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3.8/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

But this kind of hack, while it would solve your problem now, has the property of making things much harder to fix in the near future. For example, your IDE won't be aware of it and will constantly warn you about your files not being importable, and it might be tricky to assert that the path is set correctly when running your application, or test suite, or package builder, or documentation builder, ...

Which is why, as you also noted in a comment, it would be best to turn `parent` into a proper package, and update the submodule pathing to either `import .b as b__` or import `from parent import b as b__`.